# Java: JMS message delivery order for different sessions

Tags: java, jms

Recently a colleague of mine said this:

> When using different sessions for producing and consuming messages, there's no guarantee that messages are delivered in the same order in which they are produced.

Now I know that JMS does not guarantee message delivery order in general, but this 'multiple sessions' angle is new to me. Is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the JMS Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5904-10/816-5904-10.pdf) (section 4.4.10 Message Order) only the order of messages sent from a session to a destination is guaranteed (and even then with some caveats).

This means:

- the order of two messages sent from *the same session* to *two different destinations* is not defined
- the order of two messages sent from *two different sessions* to *the same destination* is not defined
- the order of two messages sent from *two different sessions* to *two different destinations* is not defined.

**Only** the order of two messages sent from *one session* to *the same destination* **is defined**.

Note that it's possible that a given JMS implementation will *usually* deliver items in the (global) order in which they are produced. But you should not rely on this in any way, since it's basically a "best effort" thing: if they can manage it, it's usually better. If they can't, they are still well within the specification and your application must be able to handle that.

**tl;dr** Yes, your colleague is correct. Note again that even the guarantee in the one-session/one-destination case is not very strong, particularly if different message options are involved (see the linked PDF for details).

Answer (score 1):

As JMS is “asynchronous”, there is never any guarantee of message delivery order.